# Eclipse reports error on my JPA project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa

Each time  I make a JPA project Eclipse reports that there are errors in my project but I do  not understand why it does so. I added image and errors below:

[image]

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Column "id" cannot be resolved
>   on table "page"   Page.java   /BreakpointJPA/src/no/breakpoint/domain line
>   14    JPA Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Column "title" cannot be
>   resolved on table
>   "page"    Page.java   /BreakpointJPA/src/no/breakpoint/domain line 18 JPA
>   Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Primary key join column "id"
>   cannot be resolved on table
>   "page"    Page.java   /BreakpointJPA/src/no/breakpoint/domain line 10 JPA
>   Problem

[image]

Comment: Can you show details of your 'page' table?

Comment: Yep, I haven't implemented the timestamps yet so thats the reason why they are not in the Page entity.

Comment: So I guess that Eclipse is saying that your Entity is not properly reflecting the state of the database? How does Eclipse knows what database you're working with? Maybe it's not using the DB you shown 'adesnqhp_javaee'?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've had the same problem, the solution for me was to refresh the database connection.

Open the JPA view, find the data source explorer. There you open Database Connection, connect with your database, hit refresh. Then make some changes in your file and save it, i added an @Column(name = "") annotation to my id field. After that the error message was gone, and i ereased the Column annotation.

The Problem seems to be that eclipse reads the database tables after establishing the first connection, after that the connection is closed. So if you, like i did, made some changes after this first connection in your database, like changing the field name from foo_id to just id, eclipse didn't know that and comes with this error.

Comment: I'll just note that you can also force a manual JPA validation using Project Explorer (Juno Service Release 2).  Right click on the project, select "Validate". This avoids having to make an unwanted change to the source file just to force the validation.

Comment: I imported classes from existing db tables and was getting "catalog X cannot be resolved for table Y". I just deleted the catalog info (which was set to the name of the database schema from which the entities were imported) in the Java code for all classes generated by Eclipse and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 9):

Old thread, however I just had the same problem and solved with an even quicker approach.

1. Project Properties --> JPA
2. Change connection to . Hit apply.
3. Change connection to previous value. Hit apply.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

**Read This if you want to solve your problem easily**

There is no problem in your Database. You just have to create a new connection from Eclipse to the same database which we do during Adding JPA capabilities to the Project.

Steps:-
Create a new database from your mysql prompt.
Right click on your Project in Eclipse/MyEclipse, then go to Properties.
Click on Eclipse/MyEclipse tab on the left and then click on JPA sub menu.
Then Click on Create new Connection. Put a new Connection name. And add the same Database. (You can opt to change your database too, but same database will also do).
Test Connection, and click on Finish.
First Time it wont show that newly created Connection name. Just Click Ok to close that Window.

Then, Right Click again on Project and then Click on Propeties. Now you can see your newly created Connection on that Connection drop down list. Selct that and Click OK.

Your Error will vanish.

Possible Reason for this error:-
Eclipse creates connection with you database everytime you connect using any project using persistence.xml, but only for the first time.
So, any changes after that, especially from the database side(table name etc.) will throw an error from Eclipse.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it

1. refreshed the connection

   - Go to Data Source Explorer
   - Select connection and right click
   - select Refresh
2. Clean the project

   - Go t Project menu
   - select clean

Answer (score 2):

Go to Data Source Explorer, disconnect the database connection, after connect the database connection, right click in your project and click in validate.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the JPA/JPA2 interfaces included in your project?  If you are using maven, you need to include a dependency for the classes.  I assume that they are since there are no red lines appearing in the import declarations, but just to be safe, you should validate that they exist.

For a JPA2 dependency, you can use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just reread your question, and realized that my answer isn't likely related to the problem, but left it here as useful info for someone else as it does relate to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id
```

Comment: Similar for title: @Column(name="title")

Answer (score 0):

Try doing code assist inside the quotes of @Column(name=""). Or open the JPA Details view and view the column name combo to see the column options. There is no validation error on the @Table(name="page") annotation, so it looks like Eclipse is finding the page table.

Answer (score 0):

The annotations look correct, are you sure your project classpath is good? try and build the entity without the id and title fields first of all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just old connection in Properties->JPA->Add connection. So refresh will not help. New connection for **correct database** will help when refresh will not.