# JPA ManytoMany Relationship "JoinColumn cannot be resolved to a type" error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

I am using Spring boot and trying to implement  many to many relationship between User and Skill. I have a table users_skills with columns user_id and skill_id. I keep getting  "JoinColumn cannot be resolved to a type" error in @JoinColumn annotations in STS when trying to implement the relationship. Below is my User class

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "users")
   public class User {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private List<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<Skill>();



protected User() {}

public User(String email,String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}    


public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id ;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email ;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName ;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName ;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="users_skills", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},              
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="skill_id")})    
public List<Skill> getSkills(){
    return skills;
}

public void setSkills(List<Skill> skills) {
    this.skills = skills ;
}

}
```

Comment: Are `user_id` and `skill_id` really the **column** names in your `users_skills` table?

Comment: yes they are.Isn't this the correct way ?

Comment: In your snippet you do not show the import statements. Your error seems to be a compilation issue in your IDE. Could it be as simple as forgotten `import javax.persistence.JoinColumn` statement?

Comment: Thank you, so stupid of me. The message of the IDE was deceiving because didn't propose the import. Please add it as an answer to accept it

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865753/eclipse-reports-error-on-my-jpa-project

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just write this at the head of your class

```
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
```

Sometime eclipse doesn't show the link to import it in context menu, but it's there. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with importing below line:

```
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
```

For, below relationship.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)   
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "id")})
        
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

I was using MySql workbench. Hope, this work for someone.